# fill select box with javascript return array

Tags: javascript

I am in a big trouble. It's 2:45am and I have been since 6pm searching for ideas or examples or whatever you wanna name it!

I have this js function called from a  but I can get it to work AT ALL.

The idea is type you city name and get suggestion in a select box. Than, from the select box you can click in one of the cities and this information going back to your form field.

There are two files: index.php (js function showhint and a form calling another .php file to load the cities as suggestions)

The code can be see at www.bfamily.net

I will be very great-full for any help.

Regards,

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: FYI: I was able to add the array in a select box but the way it is right now each item going on a separate select box which of course it's wrong - all the items should be group in a single select box.

Comment: How can we guess what you have done till now and what is your code!

Comment: you can see the code on www.bfamily.net

Answer (score 0):

May be this will be helpfull

```
if (filter_var($q, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) || !filter_var($q, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) === false) {
        if ($q !== "") {
            $str = "<select name='suggestion'>";
            $q = strtolower($q);
            $len=strlen($q);
            foreach($zipArray as $name) {
                if (stristr($q, substr($name, 0, $len))) {
                    if ($hint === "") {
                        $hint = $name.'<br/>';
                    } else {
                        $hint .= "$name".'<br/>';
                    }
                    $suggestion[] = $name;
                    $str .= "<option value='".$name."'>".$name."</option>";                
                }
            }
            $str .= "</select>";
            if(count($suggestion) > 0) echo $str
        }
    }
```

But I think the better way is to have a hidden selectBox in your html and then send json "suggestions" list from .php to your .js file from Ajax and then there add proper options to your selectBox and make it visible

Comment: what you say make completely sense but unfortunaly I am not in this level. I don't know how to do it yet. there are still a lot things to learn.

Comment: absolutly for all of us.so using  $str  may be helpfull here. @Robert Barros

Comment: hey nayeri - thanks for your help . the select box working as supposed to. now I have to figure out how to fill the input field with the selection. You can check working in my bfamily.net

Comment: just for the records. I am try get something similar as you see on https://www.montway.com TYPE 95043

Comment: [montway.com](https://www.montway.com) maybe  is using [typeaheadjs](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/)so see the examples and download it and then use it

Answer (score 0):

Add an event `onchange` on your `select` to set the value

```
function(inputName, event) {
    document.getElementByName(inputName)[0].value = event.target.selectedOptions[0].value;
}
```

But I recomand you to do something like that on your `inputs` :

```
<input type="text" name="zipCode1" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)" size="20" value="" style="text-transform:uppercase" list="suggestion">
<datalist id="suggestion">
    <option>Houston, TX 77070</option>
    <option>Cypress, TX 77433</option>
    <option>Cypress, TX 77429</option>
</datalist>
```

Of course you can either generate the `datalist` with `PHP` on the page load or with an `AJAX` request.